# What is the right way to make a synchronous MongoDB query in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, synchronous

I'm using the Node.JS driver for MongoDB, and I'd like to perform a synchronous query, like such:

```
function getAThing()
{
    var db = new mongo.Db("mydatabase", server, {});

    db.open(function(err, db)
    {
        db.authenticate("myuser", "mypassword", function(err, success)
        {
            if (success)
            {
                db.collection("Things", function(err, collection)
                {
                    collection.findOne({ name : "bob"}, function(err, thing)
                    {                           
                        return thing;
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is, db.open is an asychronous call (it doesn't block), so the getAThing returns "undefined" and I want it to return the results of the query. I'm sure I could some sort of blocking mechanism, but I'd like to know the right way to do something like this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no way to make this synchronous w/o some sort of terrible hack.  The right way is to have `getAThing` accept a callback function as a parameter and then call that function once `thing` is available.

```
function getAThing(callback)
{
    var db = new mongo.Db("mydatabase", server, {});

    db.open(function(err, db)
    {
        db.authenticate("myuser", "mypassword", function(err, success)
        {
            if (success)
            {
                db.collection("Things", function(err, collection)
                {
                    collection.findOne({ name : "bob"}, function(err, thing)
                    {       
                        db.close();                    
                        callback(err, thing);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Node 7.6+ Update**

[`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) now provides a way of coding in a synchronous *style* when using asynchronous APIs that return promises (like the native MongoDB driver does).

Using this approach, the above method can be written as:

```
async function getAThing() {
    let db = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://server/mydatabase');
    if (await db.authenticate("myuser", "mypassword")) {
        let thing = await db.collection("Things").findOne({ name: "bob" });
        await db.close();
        return thing;
    }
}
```

Which you can then call from another `async` function as `let thing = await getAThing();`.

However, it's worth noting that `MongoClient` provides a connection pool, so you shouldn't be opening and closing it within this method. Instead, call `MongoClient.connect` during your app startup and then simplify your method to:

```
async function getAThing() {
    return db.collection("Things").findOne({ name: "bob" });
}
```

Note that we don't call `await` within the method, instead directly returning the promise that's returned by `findOne`.

Comment: Thanks Johnny for this workaround! I wish there was a simple way out of the box... it is frustrating even to write a simple `if_exists()` function... Btw, if anybody knows an easier way, or an update from the driver, please post it here.

Comment: You can always use an async library, to avoid the identation of "doom" https://github.com/caolan/async That will make the code more readable and nice.

Comment: @Logan I wouldn't call it a "workaround", that is how node is designed to work.

Comment: returned ```thing``` is a '[object Promise]'. How can we read data inside  promise object? (without ```.then``` callback)

Comment: @RishithaMinol You can `await` the promise from within another `async` function: `let thing = await getAThing();`

Comment: I am trying to move away from the callback function model where it is easy to handle an error or success result, ie `function(err, result) { if (err) { res.send(err) } else { // do things }` - how do you handle/view an error that comes back from `let thing = await db.collection.findOne(query)`?

Comment: @user1063287 With `await` you have to use try/catch blocks for error handling.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - like this?  `try { var bob = await getAThing() } catch(err) { console.log("mongodb query error is here: " + err ) }`

Comment: @user1063287 Yes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await) for more examples.

Answer (score 33):

**ES 6** (Node 8+)

You can utilize [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

`await` operator pauses the execution of asynchronous function until the Promise is resolved and returns the value.

This way your code will work in synchronous way:

```
const query = MySchema.findOne({ name: /tester/gi });
const userData = await query.exec();
console.log(userData)
```

---

Older Solution - June 2013 ;)

Now the [Mongo Sync](https://npmjs.org/package/mongo-sync) is available, this is the right way to make a synchronous MongoDB query in Node.js.

I am using this for the same. You can just write sync method like below:

```
var Server = require("mongo-sync").Server;
var server = new Server('127.0.0.1');
var result = server.db("testdb").getCollection("testCollection").find().toArray();
console.log(result);
```

Note: Its dependent on the [node-fiber](https://npmjs.org/package/fibers) and some issues are there with it on windows 8.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I coded a 5 line script with mongo-sync and it failed, even though it matched their test code nearly perfectly. It seems to have bugs.

Comment: @jcollum : Can you please describe the exact issue you had? because its working for me with no major issues.. If you are sure its a bug in module you can raise a new issue on [Repo](https://github.com/olegp/mongo-sync/issues)

Comment: I submitted a bug. Apparently you have to delete the fibers modules from node_modules in the mongo-sync lib. Looks like a packaging problem.

Comment: If it's dependent on node-fiber then it's not synchronous

Comment: Unstable package. mongo-sync gives assertion failure at the time of initialization only.

Answer (score 3):

While it's not strictly synchronous, a pattern I've repeatedly adopted and found very useful is to use [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) and [promisify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify) yield on asynchronous functions. For mongo, you could rewrite the above:

```
var query = co( function* () {

    var db = new mongo.Db("mydatabase", server, {});
    db = promisify.object( db );
    db = yield db.open();

    yield db.authenticate("myuser", "mypassword");

    var collection = yield db.collection("Things");
    return yield collection.findOne( { name : "bob"} );

});

query.then( result => {

} ).catch( err => {

} );
```

This means:

1. You can write "synchronous"-like code with any asynchronous library
2. Errors are thrown from the callbacks, meaning you don't need the success check
3. You can pass the result as a promise to any other piece of code