# Mongoose.js - Return collection in a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I've been playing around with the MEAN stack and I was creating some fake data in the dummydata.js file they provide. One thing I noticed is that if I do the following, my console spits out the data I would expect it to:

```
var allBlogs = function(){
  Blog.find().exec(function(err, docs){
   console.log(docs);
 });
};

console.log(allBlogs());

//returns the data I expect
```

However, when I try to set the `console.log(docs)` as a return value my terminal says `undefined`:

```
 var allBlogs = function(){
  Blog.find().exec(function(err, docs){
   return docs;
 });
};

console.log(allBlogs());

// returns 'undefined'
```

Does anyone know why this is? Can I not return the docs from this function? Is console.logging all that is allowed?

Comment: you need to learn about asynchronous programming and callbacks.

Comment: @MukeshSoni can you push me in the right direction?

Comment: i already did. All you need to do is search google for those phrases and read to your heart's content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888792/synchronous-function-calls-for-nodejs-mongodb-driver/13889029#13889029