# MongoDart find with problems

Tags: mongodb, dart, dart-async

I am implementing a MVC framework in Dart. I am implementing the find method and I want it to return the documents from that query.

The problem is that find() doesn't wait that the operation is performed and we need to bind a function inside then().

```dart
 static find(model, [params]){
     Db db = new Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1/dart");
     var models = [];
     db.open().then((o){
         return db.collection(model).find(params).forEach((d){
         models.add(d);
         });
     });
     return models;
}
```

Right now the return from find() is []. Do you know any way of returning the documents properly?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart/blob/master/example/blog.dart

Comment: Well, that really doesn't solve my problem. I just want to get the documents return and not deciding on find what I am doing with every document. Please take a look in the Python Driver for example, about how simple is to do a find and then getting the documents just in time http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=839

Comment: when doing potentially long running calls like to a database, the execution is better when it is asynchronous, if you only want to continue after you have your data then you just put all your code in the `.then((_){/*in here*/}) callback for when the future completes. it's done like this so it doesnt lock up your program, if you do want to continue doing other stuff whilst the database is fetching data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
 static Future<List> find(model, [params]){
     Db db = new Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1/dart");
     var models = [];
     return db.open().then((o){
       db.collection(model).find(params).forEach((d){
         models.add(d);
       });
       return models;
     });
}
```

and use it like

```dart
find(model, [p1, p2, p3]).then((m) => ...);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment :) Well, that solves the problem but it isn't a clean solution. I just what that find() returns the documents.

Comment: You can't convert from async to sync execution in Dart. There are discussions and plans to add a Future.await() to allow just that. Until then (I expect several months up to more than a year), when you start async the chain of of execution stays async until it is finished.

Comment: I couldn't understand your point,  sorry. You arr saying that about mongo dart or Dart? Dart by default runs every line of code one after another.

Comment: That's about Dart. `db.open()` returns a `Future`. This means it is an async operation. Async operation get queued and the next statement is executed. Your `return models` is executed before `db.open()` returns. `db.open()` or some code in `db.open()` (where async operation starts) is not executed before the current chain of operations is finished.
https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/

Comment: Cursor.forEach returns a future (it's an async function), for safety you may wish to chain the return of models. Eg: db.collection(model).find(params).forEach((d) { models.add(d); }).then((_) => models);

Answer (score 2):

If synchronous API of your framework is absolute requirement for you, I'm afraid you are out of luck with mongo_dart.
There is no way to build synchronous facade on top of asynchronous API and mongo_dart (or any other database driver in Dart AFAIK, see [postgresql](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/postgresql) or [sqljocky](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqljocky) for example) is asynchronous.

Your experience with synchronous mongodb drivers in any other languages is not fully applicable here. Mongo_dart much more resemble mongodb driver for nodejs - asynchronous too.
For nodejs async driver you too cannot get the result synchronously, see related questions:

[Synchronous function calls for nodejs mongodb driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888792/synchronous-function-calls-for-nodejs-mongodb-driver) or 
[What is the right way to make a synchronous MongoDB query in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030248/what-is-the-right-way-to-make-a-synchronous-mongodb-query-in-node-js)

So I guess you should either embrace asynchronous code or return to python. Dart can do some things synchronously in the console applications but all the networking I believe is fully async here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am wondering, if Dart behaves like this, how it's possible to send the model data to the view... Definetly, it's a hard task trying to build a good MVC Framework for Dart.

Comment: If you indeed interested I would recommend to take a look at existing MVC (or any other MV*) frameworks in Dart. There are plenty of them - from https://github.com/PureMVC/puremvc-dart-multicore-framework to https://angulardart.org/

Comment: I do not presume that frameworks in question are good by your standards. I just believe that they solved specific problem - how to send the model data to view - in asynchronous environment.