# mongodb force synchronous to find documents

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to create a synchronous find() for a mongo query?

Like:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', function(err, db){

  if(err) throw err;

  var collection = db.collection('mycollection');

  var myarray  = collection.find({});

  //use myarray
  for (var i = myarray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(myarray[i]);
  };

});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: If you're wanting to do this in NodeJS, you should probably add it's tag.

Comment: No, there is not really a good way. Embrace the asynchronous behavior. Use Promises or a good async library if you want to maintain some sanity when dealing with complex async flows. Also, this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030248/what-is-the-right-way-to-make-a-synchronous-mongodb-query-in-node-js/16982359#16982359